# Increment a string n number of times in python list

Tags: python, string, list, list-comprehension

I have a list like below in python.

```
a = ['191.10', '10.0']
```

Now I want to create another list like below

```
b = ['191.10', '10.0', '10.1', '10.2', '10.3' and so on till '10.255']
```

Basically Increment the second string with `0.1`

How can I achieve that.

Comment: is it always the second string or the last string ?

Comment: You can't do arithmetic like that directly on a string. So convert it to a number, do the arithmetic in a loop, converting each result back to a string. If you get stuck, post your code and we can help you fix it.

Comment: Shouldn't the list end in 10.3 or another increment of 0.1 instead of 10.255?

Comment: It looks like what you're _really_ trying to do is arithmetic on IPv4 subnets? If so, you might want to consider treating them as IPv4 subnets (e.g., with the `ipaddress` library) instead of treating them as strings and implementing hard-to-guess-at arithmetic rules on them which are just going to confuse you when you read the code 6 months from now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using a list comprehension:

```
a = ['191.10', '10.0']

b = a + ['10.'+str(i) for i in range(1, 256)]
```

Result:

```
['191.10', '10.0', '10.1', '10.2', ..., '10.254', '10.255']
```

Comment: I don't think you can hard-code the 10 in the `b=..` statement. You have to extract the number before the dot in the second element of the original list. Otherwise the principle is spot on.

Comment: You could add a python 3.6 version that doesn't require the explicit call to `str`:  `[f'10.{i}' for i in range(256)]`

Comment: No, but the OP said "increment the second string by 0.1", which I thought meant increment whatever number is in the second element of the list.

Comment: What @JohnRC said. You can't just assume the last item in the input list is `'10.0'`.

Comment: In fact, I guess you shouldn't assume that it will be x.0 either, so the comprehension should start from whatever number is after the dot + 1

Answer (score -2):

The most obvious way to accomplish this is probably with the `append()` statement. Also I'm assuming you meant to write `"b = ['191.10, '10.0', '10.001', '10.002', '10.003' and so on till '10.255']"` here.

```
 a = ['191.10', '10.0']

 for n in range(1, 255):
      a.append(10 + (0.001*n))
```

Comment: Probably not, since as abarnert says, these look like  IPv4 subnets, so `'10.001'` is invalid.